# Programmatically generate an Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I use eclipse to work on an application which was originally created independently of eclipse.  As such, the application's directory structure is decidedly not eclipse-friendly.

I want to programmatically generate a project for the application.  The `.project` and `.classpath` files are easy enough to figure out, and I've learned that projects are stored in the workspace under `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects`

Unfortunately, some of the files under here (particularly `.location`) seem to be encoded in some kind of binary format.  On a hunch I tried to deserialize it using `ObjectInputStream` - no dice.  So it doesn't appear to be a serialized java object.

My question is: is there a way to generate these files automatically?

For the curious, the error I get trying to deserialize the `.location` file is the following:

`java.io.StreamCorruptedException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 40B18B81`

**Update:** My goal here is to be able to replace the New Java Project wizard with a command-line script or program.  The reason is the application in question is actually a very large J2EE/weblogic application, which I like to break down into a largish (nearly 20) collection of subprojects.  Complicating matters, we use clearcase for SCM and create a new branch for every release.  This means I need to recreate these projects for every development view (branch) I create.  This happens often enough to automate.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by writing a small Eclipse plugin.  You could even extend it out to being a "headless" RCP app, and pass in the command line arguments you need.

The barebones code to create a project is:

```
IProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
IProject project = root.getProject("DesiredProjectName");
project.create(progressMonitor);
project.open(progressMonitor);
```

Just take a look at the eclipse code for the Import Project wizard to give you a better idea of where to go with it.

Comment: This way of creating project works on eclipse plugin project. Is there any way to create a java project from standalone java project? means creating a project from main class simply by running it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer would be even more helpful if it stated where the code for the Import Project wizard can be found. Just the name of the containing package and/or the name of the implementing class might be enough to find it in the eclipse git repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Use [AntEclipse](http://ant-eclipse.sourceforge.net)

It can create eclipse projects from ant.

Answer (score 0):

To create java project you can use JavaCore from `org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore`. As a `sourceProject` you can use generic project item, which has been suggested by @James Van Huis

```java
IJavaProject javaSourceProject = JavaCore.create(sourceProject);
```