# Creating a Eclipse Java Project from another project, programatically

Tags: java, eclipse, project

I would like to create a Java project from another Java project, using some script or Java methods from an Eclipse library, whether it exists. An alternative to this can be duplicating a previously manually-created project. Is there any approach to this?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to do this programmatically or manually?

Comment: Similar Question http://stackoverflow.com/q/251807/858356

Comment: I would like to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can make use of `IProject#copy` (inherited from [IResource.copy](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource.html))

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Alexander Pavlov's answer, I found that a little extra work is required to copy the project properties (such as referenced projects) in addition to just copying the project files.

```
public static IProject copyProject(String projectName) throws CoreException {
    IProgressMonitor m = new NullProgressMonitor();
    IWorkspaceRoot workspaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    IProject project = workspaceRoot.getProject(projectName);
    IProjectDescription projectDescription = project.getDescription();
    String cloneName = projectName + "_copy";
    // create clone project in workspace
    IProjectDescription cloneDescription = workspaceRoot.getWorkspace().newProjectDescription(cloneName);
    // copy project files
    project.copy(cloneDescription, true, m);
    IProject clone = workspaceRoot.getProject(cloneName);
    // copy the project properties
    cloneDescription.setNatureIds(projectDescription.getNatureIds());
    cloneDescription.setReferencedProjects(projectDescription.getReferencedProjects());
    cloneDescription.setDynamicReferences(projectDescription.getDynamicReferences());
    cloneDescription.setBuildSpec(projectDescription.getBuildSpec());
    cloneDescription.setReferencedProjects(projectDescription.getReferencedProjects());
    clone.setDescription(cloneDescription, null);
    return clone;
}
```