# Creating Eclipse Projects Programmatically (no Plugin)

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to create some dummy projects each containing a single class for testing purpose. It seems like the usual way to go is to write an Eclipse plugin for that. However this isn't really the way I want to go, since I have no experience in creating plugins nor do I want to start an extra runtime eclipse Environment. The projects that I want to create should end up in the same workspace I'm currently working in.

So is there any way to achieve such or is writing a plugin the only way to go in that case?

Edit: Again, as far as possible I want to stay away from touching any plugin stuff. Pretty much every solution that i've seen here on Stackoverflow discusses this problem with regards to plugins. So this should (hopefully) not be a duplicate question

Comment: possible duplicate - take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251807/programmatically-generate-an-eclipse-project?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [EASE](https://eclipse.org/ease/), a scripting environment aimed at Eclipse users. Documentation is quite sparse, but there are some [sample scripts](http://git.eclipse.org/c/ease/org.eclipse.ease.scripts.git/tree/JavaScript%20Beginner%20Tutorial/02%20File%20IO/04%20Create%20sample%20project%20(java%20API).js) aimed at creating projects.